# ¿Como ordenar las carpetas y archivos de mi proyecto web?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hosting, diseño

Me gustaría saber cómo debo de ordenar las carpetas y sus diversos archivos (index.html, scss, js, multimedia, páginas web secundarias) de la mejor y más optimizada forma.

Comment: Tu pregunta se basa en opiniones y puede terminar cerrada por favor evita crear este tipo de preguntas.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

En general, dependiendo del tipo de proyecto, es una buena idea comenzar con una plantilla de aplicación de muestra y verificar su estructura predeterminada. Por ejemplo, **ASP.NET MVC5** o **ASP.NET Core MVC/Razor** tienen su propia estructura de carpetas recomendada en la que puede construir y ajustar según sus necesidades **si** ocurre alguna.

Dependiendo de qué proyecto web en particular sea (qué marco, idioma, etc.), puede buscar las mejores prácticas para ese tipo en particular. Por supuesto, hay algunas ideas generales sobre la separación de preocupaciones, como no mezclar varios tipos de lógica (presentación, negocios, etc.), pero hay muchos recursos que tratan esos principios generales en línea.

Answer (score -4):

Por lo que tengo entendido, no existe una forma única, pero podemos encontrar recomendaciones como la que te indico en el siguiente link:

https://geekytheory.com/estructura-de-un-proyecto-web